# removing action from local.xml

Tags: magento

How can i remove `<action method="addCartLink"></action>` from local.xml. This code in customer.xml:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method on `top.links` called `removeLinkByUrl` that should do it for you. I haven't tested this, so you may need the full URL, but the gist is this:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
</reference>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: How can i get the full url `<url>checkout/cart</url>`